# Certificate for Odoo to use as SP in saml auth with Shibboleth IDP

Tags: odoo, ubuntu-16.04, saml-2.0, odoo-9, odoo-10

I would like to know how can I generate a signed certificate for Odoo to use as SP for saml authentication with Shibboleth as IDP. I need to generate this in my localhost first, so is it the usual certificate generation procedure in ubuntu with apache or is there any difference in the case of Odoo?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend going to https://www.samltool.com/online_tools.php as it has utilities to generate SAML certs (among other things)